# Spring Hibernate 6 - Change application.properties environment on start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite

I just migrated from Hibernate 5.6 to 6.4, and one of the required changes is to change `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` from `org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect` to `org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect`.

It is easy to change the default value, but many people self-host my program with their custom configuration files that contain the old setting, and I don't want to require everyone to manually change this field during an upgrade because some people might miss it and encounter an error on start. Is there a way to automatically / programmatically detect and change the old config value when the application starts and before Hibernate initializes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate the dialect property anyway. It spread widely for a false reason.

By default hibernate decide best what dialect to use. But you have to fulfill two conditions:

1. The driver-manager must be aware of the jdbc-driver-class.
2. Hibernate must know the jdbc-url.

Since the jdbc-url is unique for the driver and the jdbc-driver-class knows what version must be used, hibernate should decide all by its own what dialect to use.

Try to remove the dialect property and use

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new YourDBDriver());
```

However if you are registering the driver at startup in an WAR (Web-Archive) you might unregister the driver on shutdown of the app (or you might get a warning in the log what is unprofessional).